What would happen if our blood was gold based?
This is my first time using this site so bear with me.
In my novel, you can tell a person is non-homo sapiens when their blood is based on gold. They do not consume oxygen, thus do not actively breath. They look like them but aren't quite human but more related to a supernatural alien (they aren't aliens in my story but let's go with that).
Maybe their body would rust? I'm open to any more information concerning gold-based blood. The whole point of my idea was the gold colored blood but I'm not sure if that's possible.
EDIT: fixed some stuff.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Since you are new - this question has a few issues - the first one being - One question per post. I am seeing five questions. Furthermore, we arent a brainstorming site. As an aside, answering this question in terms of Chemistry is boring (Gold isnt reactive and would be bad in that sense) - but a question about the societal impact of a species whose blood potentially could be rather valuable - now that is interesting

@TheDemonLord Yes, that was exactly my idea-- that gold-based blood could heal a certain viral illness that came to be when these aliens arrived to land. I've fixed my question, thank you for the remark.

Gold based? In what sense? Rather than iron based? The most obvious thing that springs to mind is that gold doesn't oxidise, so from a science based tag perspective it wouldn't work, you say they don't breath (use oxygen presumably?) so I guess that's fine .. however it does beg the question why they have any substantial quantity of gold in their blood, what purpose does it serve that would cause any evolution to result in that? Of course if it's just magic it hardly matters and just is, so you hardly need to be asking here or worrying about the science or biology

@TheDemonLord Lacking any details to the contrary & presuming the gold content to be equivalent to our bloods iron content and their bodies to contain a similar volume of blood > then according to Googles AI (so who knows if it's right ) a typical adult human has 2.5 grams of iron in their blood, further queries of Googles AI gives values for 2.5 grams of gold ranging between £205 and £170, so not to be sneezed at, but not a great amount either, and you'd have to extract it, no idea how time & labour consuming and costly that might be..

@Pelinore Hypothetically though... what would be some other symptoms? They could have gold blood due to the aliens having gold blood so through body liquid transfusion (blood, saliva, etc) an ordinary man could be slowly get affected by it

OK, you're down to one question in the body, but it doesn't really match the title of the post. As per the comments of others, gold is not reactive - blood is (mostly) for transporting oxygen and gold is terrible for doing that. That rules out a science-based answer. I'd suggest that you may wish to take this to the Sandbox https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9981/sandbox-for-proposed-questions and get some advice on developing this into a better question - possibly look at gold-coloured blood unless the element itself is important for your story.

.. @TheDemonLord .. could perhaps be economically viable, but perhaps not sufficiently so after other expenses for most to consider murder

@KerrAvon2055 All right.

What springs to my mind is: what purpose does the blood even have in your creature? In the human (and almost every creature that dvells on this planet) the main purpose of blood is to bring oxygen from the lungs to all the organs. I'd advice you to take this question to the "sandbox" first. It is a dedicated thread on the Wordbuilding Meta stack to help people refine their questions so they become actually answerable.

@Gamahucher Well lacking other pigmentation to obscure it (if they were light skinned) it might effect their appearance in the same way our blood gives us a pinkish tone of sorts, other than that I can't think of much off the top of my head, it's not going to have much effect at all on ordinary humans exposed to it though, gold is pretty biologically unreactive, no one's going to use their blood for transfusions because it won't work as blood for us, anemia if enough of your own blood was replaced with this is to be expected, death from oxygen starvation if most is replaced, that's about it.

@Pelinore - Obviously, the details are highly suspect, but (for example) a human kidney fetches somewhere between $2000/$20000.  So if you're willing to entirely exsanguinate someone for a few hundred dollars of gold, there are much easier and more lucrative unpleasant things to do to people.

You might try caesium instead .. gold coloured (kinda), reactive, and spontaneously ignites in air which could be fun for anyone trying to fight one in close quarters with sharp weapons

Hmm.. caesium auride (caesium gold alloy) "hydrolyzes readily" providing caesium hydroxide, gold and hydrogen.. maybe be we have a bio-chemist in the house who can suggest some (vaguely implausible quasi sorta) plausible chemical process by which caesium might serve for respiration?

I'm going to focus on the "gold colored blood" bit, as Pica has done a good job on the chemistry already.
The problem is that gold colored blood doesn't come from gold. Gold in solution is clear, and there's a famous story of a chemist who, to hide his colleague's Nobel prize medal from the Nazis, dissolved it and left the colorless solution on a shelf until after the war, when he precipatiated it back out and the Nobel committee remade it.
But, ok, so a gold solution won't give you the result you want, what about gold particles? Nope, they give all kinds of pretty colors, but don't look like gold in solution. Gold flakes might work, but they'd have to be super dense. So, what is your answer? Beetle shells, I'd argue.
Your creature's blood contains proteins with similar iridescent structure to beetle shells. Not sure why, you maybe don't need to explain it. But it sparkles, and looks like liquid gold. Which probably unfortunately makes a whole load of people hunt the aliens for their blood out of ignorance. The chemistry isn't explicitly ruled out, the aliens can function in a very similar way to us, and everyone is happy, apart from the aliens and alien exsanguinators, for very different reasons.

So, we are not using iron as itself- but iron bound to protein - ferritin.
https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/31970541/
You would need something similar for the gold. Where the problem starts- gold is not prone to bind- to pretty much anything. It just sits there, accumulating. You can have that with iron too. For which the treatment is bloodletting.
The only way to get gold chemically uninert- is a very active environment. As in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aqua_regia active. I fail to see how that can be archieved without denaturing proteins.
